# How to use 'fetchData' method in react native with authentication header and body with POST method for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

In my current iOS project I need to fetch data from api call with POST method along with login credentials(userName & Password) as authentication header  in react native javaScript file.

Can someone Please help me on that.

[refernce screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQCfA.png)

Comment: Update your tag, what framework are you using if you are using JS with iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the fetch method to 'POST', add in headers and body as key-value pairs and process response. Here is an example.

```
var bodyMap = {};
// fill in the body map with keyvalue pair
fetch(POST_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': authValue,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyMap)
      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData);
          //process response 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks  Irfan Ayaz.
Can you please explain, how to get the  'authValue'  with userName & Password from the snippet ?

Comment: That depends upon how the server is expecting it.

Comment: Server expecting authorisation value in Base 64.

Comment: How in base64? Looks like you are not clear enough. What key-value pair server is expecting username and password in? You can't just generate authvalue from both using base64. I can help you out if you can get the required info from server.

Comment: Please guide how can we do with axios in react-native