# Get API data with POST method in react-native with axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I need to get data in react-native app with axios. I can get data with simple GET method as below:

```
class AlbumList extends Component {

  state = { albums: [] };

componentWillMount() {
  //axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums') .then(response => console.log(response));
  axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')

  .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
        }
        renderAlbums() {
          return this.state.albums.map(album =>
          <AlbumDetail key={album.title} album={album} />);
         // return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{album.title}</Text>);
        }

render() {
    console.log(this.state);

return (
   <View>
        {this.renderAlbums()}
    </View>    
);
}
}
```

How can i get data from API with `POST` method and I also need to pass header and api-username,api-password, apitoken ?

I need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358543/949003 but with **AXIOS**.

**Edit:**

I need to get data from [LINNWORK](https://apps.linnworks.net/Api/Method/Inventory-GetCategories) API. if someone had done this please guide. They first need to [authorize](https://apps.linnworks.net/Api/Method/Auth-AuthorizeByApplication) and then I can get data from there. So authrize and then next step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

axios `post` method takes 3 arguments i.e. url, data & config.

you can structure axios post request as follows:

```
axios.post(
    'http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums', 
    {
       'param1': 'value1',
       'param2': 'value2',
       //other data key value pairs
    },
    {
       headers: {
           'api-token': 'xyz',
            //other header fields
       }
    }
);
```

In your case you need to access `https://api.linnworks.net/api/Inventory/GetCategories`, which according to [docs](https://apps.linnworks.net/Api/Method/Inventory-GetCategories) requires `token` from auth api in `Authorization` header. So your GET request via axios will be:

```
axios.get("https://api.linnworks.net/api/Inventory/GetCategories", { 
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'token-from-auth-api'
    }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

Comment: Your output is very valuable and please check EDIT so that I can sort out the issue. Big Thanks

Comment: @Jai are you able to generate access token from auth api ?

Comment: I have access token and username password that's used in CakePHP project.  I will use same in react native app.

Comment: @Jai can you share the details over private conversation ? It'll be more easy to help you out then

Comment: Ok. Please let me know how to have private conversation?

Comment: @Jai start a private chat room using this [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4614728/deepansh-sachdeva)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163297/discussion-between-jai-and-deepansh-sachdeva).

Comment: can you please check chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163296/room-for-jai-and-deepansh-sachdeva

Comment: someone has requested you to check post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48395471/949003. I tried it but i could not help him.