# Passing Parameters with axios in react-native android app

Tags: parameter-passing, react-native, axios

I require to pass some parameters with AXIOS in react-native but don't know how should I pass parameters with AXIOS.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48223906/5306371) useful but its not fully satisfy my issue. I need to pass below parameters to fetch all items from API:

Working example in PHP:

> $url = 'https://APISITE.net/api/Stock/GetStockItems?keyWord=6666777788889&locationId=""&entriesPerPage=10000&pageNumber=1&excludeComposites=true';

Its working well in PHP TEST file and i only need to pass **keyword** value ie **6666777788889**  to get data.

I dont know how to pass these values in AXIOS. Please guide.

Comment: @Deepansh Sachdeva Can you please check this?

Comment: where do you get value in `@value` ?

Comment: I updated post. Please check and i know you can easily answer this as I see your last answer in linked post. Thanks

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva     ,  I really need to explore AXIOS but there is no good documentation for this. Only found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios/  which is (i believe) not useful .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `params` in the config of axios request.

```
axios.get('https://APISITE.net/api/Stock/GetStockItems', {
    params: {
        keyWord: 666677788899,
        locationId: 2,
        entriesPerPage: 100000,
        pageNumber: 1,
        excludeComposites: true,
        //add other params
    }
})
```

You can check axios's github [Readme](https://github.com/axios/axios) page for reference.

Comment: Can add value of keyword dynamically like {product.StockItemId} ? First I passed statically but need to pass dynamically. You can redirect me for some other post/link if something same is done.

Comment: Added new post for another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48442837/5306371