# Parameter pass from one api to another in react-native

Tags: react-native, parameter-passing, axios

I want to pass a parameter value from one API-Request to 2nd API-request so that 2nd api display result accordingly: Here is my function `componentWillMount`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.post('https://APISITE/api/Auth/AuthorizeByApplication?applicationId=b72fc47a-ef82-4cb3-8179-2113f09c50ff&applicationSecret=e727f554-7d27-4fd2-bcaf-dad3e0079821&token=cd431b31abd667bbb1e947be42077e9d')
  .then((response) => { console.log(response.data); });

      axios.get('https://APISITE//api/Stock/GetStockItems',

        { 
            params: {
                keyWord: 454534534543,
                locationId: '',
                entriesPerPage: 100000,
                pageNumber: 1,
                excludeComposites: true,
                //add other params
            },
            headers: 
            { Authorization: 'asdfasdsfdfdfdfsfsdxxx' 
            }
        //}).then((response) => { console.log(response.data); }); 
         }).then((response) => this.setState({ products: response.data }));

         axios.get('https://APISITE//api/Stock/GetStockLevel', {  

            params: { 
                stockItemId: '2f80b45c-85ff-449b-9ad6-ffcc4bb640dd',
                 },
                   headers: 
                   { Authorization: 'asdfasdsfdfdfdfsfsdxxx'
                   }       
      //  }).then(response => console.log(response));
        }).then((response) => this.setState({ racks: response.data }));
}
```

Value in  **stockItemId** is passed as static value and result displayed in console correctly. How can get stockItemId's value dynamically from 1st-api request?

**Edit:** Below is data result screenShots of passing stockItemId directly in api and getting from 1st api.

- Getting from 1st api: `stockItemId: stockItems.data.StockItemId` : http://prntscr.com/i7k0j7
- Directly passing value of stockItemId screenshot- `stockItemId: '2f80b45c-85ff-449b-9ad6-ffcc4bb640dd'` http://prntscr.com/i7jyq7

Answer (score 1):

**First** thing ***never*** use `componentWillMount` component life cycle method to ***set the component state or call any api request*** for these purpose use `componentDidMount` for more reading which life cycle use for which purpose read **[this article](https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1)** and **Secondly** just add the second api request inside the first api request response with different name response name as given below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.post('https://APISITE/api/Auth/AuthorizeByApplication?
        applicationId='app id'&applicationSecret='app secret'&token='app token'')
    .then((responseFirst) => { 
        axios.get('https://APISITE//api/Stock/GetStockItems', { 
            params: {
                keyWord: 5055967419551,
                locationId: '',
                entriesPerPage: 100000,
                pageNumber: 1,
                excludeComposites: true,
            },
            headers: { 
                Authorization: '0f32ae0d-c4e0-4aca-8367-0af88213d668' 
            }
        }).then((responseSecond) => this.setState({ products: responseSecond.data }));

            axios.get('https://APISITE//api/Stock/GetStockLevel', {  
                params: { 
                    stockItemId: responseFirst.data.stockItemId,
                },
                headers: { 
                    Authorization: '0f32ae0d-c4e0-4aca-8367-0af88213d668'
                }       
            }).then((responseThird) => this.setState({ racks: responseThird.data }));
    });
}
```

if you are using redux then read [redux documentation to handle async type actions](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) and how to handle it.

Comment: Its displaying error message: "response is not defined" what to do?

Comment: could you please be specify on which line you getting this error? I gave you generalize answer but variable and response handling you have to do this.

Comment: The second request should be within the ‘then’ function on the first request. That should solve the error message you are getting.

Comment: Getting error on line: "stockItemId: response.data.stockItemId,"

Comment: @RobWalker ...i tried that too but it didnt work.same error

Comment: I thought it would be simple but I stuck here :(

Comment: @Sharma try to use these api requests in the redux action so you can handle asynchronous requests as well as api requests.

Comment: Ok. Will try with that. Can you pls add code in answer with example REDUX requests?

Comment: @ShahzadMirza I edit the post and added the console screen shot. Pls have a look at those. Thank You.

Comment: I think it should be possible with this and no need of redux here. Can you please look at EDIT section and can help me out.

Comment: try this updated solution that I gave you otherwise you can use `let stockItemId` and update its value in first api request and then use same variable in your required location.

Comment: OK . trying. Thanks

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use "LET stockItemId"? I am still struggling on it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the response data from within the `then` functions.
Notice the way the response from each request is passed into the following `then` where it can easily used.

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios
    .post('https://APISITE/api/Auth/AuthorizeByApplication?applicationId='app id'&applicationSecret='app secret'&token='app token'')
    .then((authData) => {
      console.log(authData.data);
      return axios.get('https://APISITE//api/Stock/GetStockItems', {
        params: {
          keyWord: 5055967419551,
          locationId: '',
          entriesPerPage: 100000,
          pageNumber: 1,
          excludeComposites: true,
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: '0f32ae0d-c4e0-4aca-8367-0af88213d668'
        }
      })
    })
    .then((stockItems) => {
      this.setState({ products: stockItems.data })
      return axios.get('https://APISITE//api/Stock/GetStockLevel', {
        params: {
          stockItemId: stockItems.data.stockItemId,
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: '0f32ae0d-c4e0-4aca-8367-0af88213d668'
        }
      })
    })
    .then((stockLevel) =>
      this.setState({ racks: stockLevel.data })
    )
}
```

(This code is untested!)

Comment: I tried with this way but stockItemId is not coming with this: stockItemId: stockItems.data.StockItemId,Please suggest some other way.

Comment: @Sharma have you tried logging out what data stockItems actually contains, incase your looking for some data that does not exist where you expect?

Comment: I didnt understand. And about stockItemId, if i pass value directly as **** stockItemId: '2f80b45c-85ff-449b-9ad6-ffcc4bb640dd' **** instead of ****stockItemId: stockItems.data.StockItemId, **** then it display result

Comment: @Sharma I can’t tell you what’s wrong here without seeing your data. Look at some docs for console.log to learn how to debug the API request to properly to inspect the data(or learn to use the chrome network inspector)

Comment: I EDITed the post and you can see the chrome console. I hope it can explain my issue well. Holding on you :) Thanks

Comment: Can you please look at it. waiting for your respone.

Comment: I am still struggling on it. Please help if you have some time to check.